# Create a crosshair openGL

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics

How do I draw a white crosshair in the middle of screen in openGL, it's all well and good knowing how to render objects in 3d space, but I have literally no idea on how to draw something that sticks on the screen no matter what

Would this require a shader? one that does not take into account model view projection matrix? at what point would i draw the cross? after everything to coincide with the painters algorithm? Or do I give it a z value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a cross-hair, all you would need to do is render a piece of geometry using just a screen-space transformation, followed by the projection matrix. Mapping the identity matrix as your view will do this for you. A view matrix allows us to transform vertices into view space; removing this step allows us to go directly from model-space to screen-space. This will make it so that no matter how you turn, the reticle will stay in the same position.

Comment: One thing you should be careful with is that, when the View matrix is applied, we usually tend to define XY-plane as the "ground", but when the View matrix is removed, the XY-plane now becomes "the screen", and so no lines that are parallel to the Z-axis are displayed. I defined my crosshair as a line parallel to the Z-axis, and it didn't display itself.